# Is php a module in itself

Tags: php, apache, module, centos, ini

so in my php.ini configuration, i c this module:

```
[PHP]
```

Anything in '[]' brackets are considered modules for php, so by definition php is a module in itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

The sections in the PHP configuration file (`[section]`) are ignored by PHP when parsing the file. While some sample configuration files use them to separate directives relating to different modules, this is purely an organizational convention, and has no significance.

Comment: ty, best answer i got in a while